# Insert separate each digit by delimiter a comma

Tags: vb.net

I have in Textbox1.Text these lines:

```
27
408
73
49
80
71
70
```

I want to put a comma between each number separately. I want to do this automatically, put a comma between characters.

like: note: where there are 3 characters, like 408, it will be 40,8 when it is 70, it will be 7,0. this I think I can do, if I have an example code that separates my characters with a comma.

```
2,7
40,8
7,3
4,9
8,0
7,1
7,0
```

Code: this code does not work properly. displays many values and incorrectly type 3.3,, 4,5,6,7,78, etc, and many lines. what he shouldn't do.

```
 Dim XStrsLength = TextboxIndex1.Text.Length
        Dim XStrs As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim str As String = TextboxIndex1.Text
        Dim last As Integer
        For interval As Integer = 1 To XStrsLength
            Dim xstr As String = ""
            For I As Integer = 0 To str.Length - interval - 1 Step interval
                xstr &= str.Substring(I, interval) & ","
                last = I
            Next
            xstr &= str.Substring(last + interval)
            XStrs.Add(xstr)
        Next interval
TextBox1.Text = String.Join("", XStrs)
```

Comment: Declare a StringBuilder, loop the TextBox.Lines array, add a comma: `[StringBuilder].AppendLine(string.Concat(line.Take(line.Length - 1)) + ',' + line(line.Length - 1))`, set `TextBox.Text = [StringBuilder].ToString()` when the loop is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.  It parses whatever is in TextBox1 and places the result into TextBox2:

```
Private Sub Test()
   Dim pieces() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   Dim str As String = ""

   For Each piece As String In pieces
      str &= piece.Insert(piece.Length - 1, ",") & ControlChars.CrLf
   Next

   TextBox2.Text = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: How about TextBox1.Lines?

Comment: @Mary That would certainly work, too, and perhaps be a little more clean.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `String.Insert(Integer, String)` to insert a comma:

if the line has 2 chars: `yourline.Insert(1, ",")`

else if it has 3 chars:  `yourline.Insert(2, ",")`